# Server Issue Blank Page - Apache, Linux, Joomla

Tags: php, linux, apache, joomla

I transferred my Joomla! directory and database from a CentOS server hosted by Arvixe to a RedHat server that I have. When I browse to my Joomla! directory in my web browser all I get is a blank page. I already edited the configuration.php to the correct settings and all I am getting is a blank page, i can't get to the administrator backend either. Any suggestions?

Comment: start by looking under the process explorer?

Comment: Oh, sorry, thought it was a personal web server :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enable error logging and retry on browser. then check httpd error log.

Finally, look at database if it has configuration within a table.

Comment: When i do the move to a local CentOS server it works fine but on this RedHat server it isn't working. How do I enable error logging and check the httpd error log? The database has no configuration within a table.

Comment: `/var/log/httpd` you ll find access and error log for httpd. `less` or `tail` error_log

Comment: I got the following error: PHP Fatal error: Class 'DateTime' not found in /var/www/html/ads/libraries/joomla/utilities/date.php on line 20

Comment: apperantly u didnt copy everything you need for joomla to work. make sure you copy all the files across servers.

Comment: The error is actually due to an older version of PHP installed on the server. This is what causes this error. The folder was copied completely.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) is blocking access to some of your content. Check `dmesg(1)` or `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for AVC rejection / denied messages. If no, then you'll have to look in your HTTPD server logs for details.